# Webdriver - open browser on full screen

Tags: firefox, webdriver

I use Webdriver remotely with firefox.

I want to open my browser on full screen. The browser is opened on full screen, but immediately minimize and moves to other program which open on my OS. When I run my webdriver locally, the broser is opened on full screen, and doesn't minimize (it stays in the browser, and doesn't move to other program). I want that my browser would open on full screen, and stay in the browser, even if I run my test remottley.

The reason is that I used Java Robot, and I have to be in the browser in order that my action would be performed.

Thank you.

Comment: Please make your question more clear.

Answer (score 23):

I don't know I really understood your question, but have a look at

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

Comment: This returns an error for me using Selenium 3:  AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'manage'  --- This worked for me instead: driver.maximize_window()

Answer (score 4):

**https://technicaltesting.wordpress.com/category/webdriver/#3**

Especially handy when combining Sikuli and WebDriver, you need to be absolutely sure that as much as possible is visible on the screen.
1

```
((FirefoxDriver)driver).getKeyboard().pressKey(Keys.F11);
```

If you want to hide the header, please add this in the code.

```
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
    profile.setPreference("browser.fullscreen.autohide",true);
    profile.setPreference("browser.fullscreen.animateUp",0);

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);

    ((FirefoxDriver)driver).getKeyboard().pressKey(Keys.F11);
    driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1024, 768));
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.focus()");
    Robot robot;
    try {
    robot = new Robot();
    robot.mouseMove(300,300);
    robot.mouseMove(250,300);
    } catch (AWTException e1) {

        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for FirefoxProfile & Mousemove!

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead:

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.focus();");
```

Answer (score 3):

In Python, you can do something like this. Make sure you use latest Selenium package.

```
 driver = webdriver.Firefox()
 driver.maximize_window()
 driver.implicitly_wait(30)
```

Comment: maximize_window is different than fullscreen_window.  also, no need for the implicit wait, since it has nothing to do with running a browser in full screen.

Answer (score 0):

in 2022:

```
from selenium import webdriver


f = webdriver.Firefox()
f.get('https://duckduckgo.com')
f.fullscreen_window()
```

Answer (score -1):

I stumbled upon the same problem, but I found @Chen 's F11 profile not reliable enough, so I came up with my own solution: by simply making the browser window larger than the screen so the actual content matches up perfectly with the size of the screen.

```
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    java.awt.Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    Window window = driver.manage().window();
    window.setPosition(new Point(-7, -87));
    window.setSize(new Dimension((int) screenSize.getWidth() + 14, (int) screenSize.getHeight() + 94));
```