# VK_F11 key code doesn't switch browser into full screen mode

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, awtrobot

Using AWT Robot with Selenium WebDriver + Java, I want to switch browser to full screen mode(that we achieve manually using hitting `F11` key). Hence, I wrote following code:

```
  @Test
  public void f() throws AWTException, InterruptedException {
      Robot robot = new Robot();
      WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
      driver.get("http://www.google.com");
      driver.manage().window().maximize();
      Thread.sleep(2000);
      robot.setAutoDelay(50);
      robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F11);
      Thread.sleep(5000);
      driver.quit();
  }
```

But browser doesn't switch to full screen. Can someone suggest, how can I achieve that?

Comment: The suggestions on this question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14951330/webdriver-open-browser-on-full-screen

Comment: No, that is not what I want. I want the full screen which is obtained by hitting F11 key on browser.

Comment: I was referring to these 2 lines in one of the responses `((FirefoxDriver)driver).getKeyboard().pressKey(Keys.F11);` and    `((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.focus()");`